# java servlets in web application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I may sound a little childish but i am bit confused over a very basic thing

---

I am using tomcat server.
I wrote two servlets to include in my web application and saved them in the classes folder under the tomcat directory...the point I am wondering about is I didn't compiled the two classes and simply placed the .java files in it....still my application was running successfully.....
how come this is possible??
does it has some sort of inbuild compiler or is it something else....

Comment: can you specify tomcat version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat has a feature called [Client Deployer](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Client_Deployer_Package) that allows you to do this, but as mentioned, this will only run on that Tomcat instance

Comment: From the ant file, it looks like it will remain in the WEB-INF/classes folder. The tomcat client deployer will have a build.xml that has a default target of "compile". This takes the source files from WEB-INF/classes and puts the compiled files in the same location